# In neutrinoless double beta decay, what happens when the neutrino(s) is/are absorbed? Is a lepton released, as per usual?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, neutrinos, radioactivity

Neutrinos are detected when they 'hit' a nucleus and are re-directed (z-boson) or 'create' a leptons that matches the type of neutrino....

What happens when the neutrino(s) in a neutrinoless double beta decay are (re)absorbed by the nucleus?  Does the nucleus have to emit a third electron?

Comment: There is actually *one* neutrino emitted by one nucleon and then absorbed in the nucleus (which would violate lepton number since two electron decay). I think this process is mediated by the $W^-$ boson and not the neutral Z boson. Why do you think the nucleus will then have to re-emit another third electron?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrinoless_double_beta_decay).

Answer (score 0):

In neutrinoless double beta decay, two electrons are released. So, using your model language: the first nucleus emits one electron and one antineutrino. This antineutrino is then re-absorbed as a neutrino by the other nucleus, which in turn too emits one electron. So there's only two electrons. From wikipedia comes this plot that says it all:

[image]

Comment: Or it could be two positrons.

Comment: well, yes, but then it's called neutrinoless double positron decay